# $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition - Is the graph accurate?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I am going through an introductory course on [Calculus](https://www.stewartcalculus.com/media/11_home.php).

In chapter 2, section 2.4, p 111, the author presents the following graphs to illustrate the $\varepsilon-\delta$ limit.

[image]

I have understood the epsilon-delta definition but I think that the fig 5 and 6 are inaccurate.

Bare with me as I am trying to understand the material better.

The correct fig should look like this (notice the red horizontal line, which indicates $y=L+\varepsilon$):

[image]

**Edit::**

The rationale behind this is as follows:

The function $f$ maps all the points in the interval $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$ into the interval $(L-\varepsilon, L+\varepsilon)$. So $f(a-\delta)$ should lie below the $y=L+\varepsilon$.

Am I right?

Comment: Do you mean that we should have the red line *instead* of the dashed line?

Comment: No, the first set of figures is good : you have only to guarantee that $f((a-\delta,a+\delta)) \subset (L-\varepsilon, L+\varepsilon)$ but not  the equality instead of the inclusion

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the red line indicates the  `y=L+e` line. Is that correct?

Comment: No that's not exactly what is needed. The values of $f$ should lie between $L-\epsilon $ and $L+\epsilon $ and not that $f$ should take every value between $L-\epsilon $ and $L+\epsilon $.

Comment: @JeanMarie, if that's the case, then [this](https://youtu.be/kfF40MiS7zA?t=374) video is misleading.

Comment: Yeah that video is indeed misleading. In fact there is another issue. If one tries to find the inverse image $f^{-1}((L-\epsilon, L+\epsilon) ) $ for the function used there you will get an interval like $(a-\delta', a+\delta) $ where $\delta\neq \delta'$. I don't know if this was done intentionally in the video or not. Anyway like most books on calculus there can be issues in videos on calculus. Most approaches to explaining calculus try to water it down. Sad but true.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks, I think I am moving in the right direction. BTW, why $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition is defined on the closed interval?

Comment: The definition is not based on closed intervals, rather its based on open intervals.

Comment: Moreover the idea here is not to find the inverse image $f^{-1}((L-\epsilon, L+\epsilon)) $ but rather to find a suitable $\delta $ such that image $f((a-\delta, a+\delta)) $ is a subset of $(L-\epsilon, L+\epsilon) $. If you are trying to use any idea based on inverse function to find $\delta $ then you are doing it the wrong way and credit should be deducted for it.

Comment: Yeah, $f((a-\delta,a+\delta)) \subset (L-\varepsilon, L+\varepsilon)$ is a critical point. I'm still having trouble proving limits using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legend means: "when $x$ is in here, $f(x)$ is in here" and the figure is right.

The converse condition "when $f(x)$ is in here, $x$ is in here" is not required.

---

In other terms,

$$f([x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta])\subseteq[L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon],$$ not
$$f([x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta])= [L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon].$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand this from definition of limits itself. We say that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) =L$ if
For every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists a $\delta\gt0$ such that if $x$ satisfies $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x) - L|\lt \epsilon $
Now note that the figures 5 and 6, which you may think to be inaccurate are not inaccurate because (see the figures 5 and 6)if $x$ satisfies $0<|x-a|\lt \delta$ then $|f(x)-L| \lt \epsilon$ 
On the other hand, you are considering the converse (if f satisfies $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon$ then $0<|x-a|<\delta$) of the above implication. And converse of an implication is not necessarily true. 
To be more specific, if you consider the red horizontal line, you are considering an another $\epsilon \gt 0$ (lesser than the previous epsilon, as per fig 5),for which $\delta>0 $ will be different (lesser than previous delta, as per fig 5).